# MSI not installing files to users file system

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-xp, windows-installer

I have an MSI file that, along with deploying my executable, I want to install other files (not at all related to .NET) in another vendor's subfolder under the Program Files folder.  I designed the MSI file structure to do just that and all the files show up underneath the Installer Project in VS.  When I do a test install on my computer, all the files are installed correctly, but they are not being deployed to the users computer.  Am I missing a setting/property in VS?  Do I need the files to be copied to some sort of temp directory first?

Comment: Is the target machine 64-bit? if yes, in that case you will see the files inside `Program Files (x86)` folder.

Comment: Does the setup asks to deploy for current user or all users?

Comment: It does ask. It defaults to "all users".

Comment: What's the target OS? Vista or Windows 7? If so, UAC may be the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly it is very bad practice to deploy any files whatsoever to a different vendor's installation folder, but sometimes you have to - particularly for **plug-in installations**.

I don't quite follow what you write, but your files may end up in a different overall location than "**program Files**", for example under "**common files**" or "**application settings**".

I would **run an admin install** on your setup to see how your files extract from the MSI. Just open a command prompt and type `msiexec /a yourmsi.msi` and then specify an extract location. Then you will most likely see that files are going to a different location than you expected.